Combine data from different scripts into a dataframe
I have multiple python scripts that read different csv/excel files that are received every day. The scripts export multiple dataframes to the same excel file, but on different sheets. I need to take it a step further and take specific data from each dataframe, combine them into a new, separate dataframe on another sheet in the same file. Keep in mind the scripts are seperate from one another.
For instance, let's say I have the following dataframes in an excel file:
Sheet1:

ID   Counterparty   Date         Commodity   Deal    Price   Total
--   ------------   -----        --------    -----   -----  ------
1     party1        04/03/2024     Oil       Sell    10.00   100.00
1     party1        04/03/2024     Oil       Sell    10.00   100.00
1     party1        04/03/2024     Oil       Sell    10.00   100.00
1     party1        04/03/2024     Oil       Buy    10.00   100.00
1     party1        04/03/2024     Oil       Buy    10.00   100.00
1     party1        04/03/2024     Oil       Buy    10.00   100.00

Sheet2:

ID   Counterparty   Date         Commodity   Deal    Price   Total
--   ------------   -----        --------    -----   -----  ------
1     party2        04/03/2024     Oil       Sell    5.00   50.00
1     party2        04/03/2024     Oil       Sell    5.00   50.00
1     party2        04/03/2024     Oil       Sell    5.00   50.00
1     party2        04/03/2024     Oil       Buy    5.00   50.00
1     party2        04/03/2024     Oil       Buy    5.00   50.00
1     party2        04/03/2024     Oil       Buy    5.00   50.00


On sheet 3 I need the following dataframe:
Sell
          Oil    ... ... ... 
party 1   300.00 ... ... ... 
party 2   150.00 ... ... ...

Buy
          Oil    ... ... ... 
party 1   300.00 ... ... ... 
party 2   150.00 ... ... ...

Is this even possible to achieve? I have no idea the first place to even start with something like this? Any type of suggestions would help. If you need any other information, just let me know

It looks like the general process would be to read each sheet into a pandas dataframe, then concat into a single table. Then perform the aggregations for your desired output, looks like group by Counterparty, Commodity, etc., then pivot Commodity into columns - I'm making educated guesses based on your samples. If all the files are being parsed at the same time you could just add this final aggregation at the end of the existing script rather than reading each sheet from your output file.

I see two solutions: (1) create another script which will read data from 2 sheets and it will create 3rd sheet - and you have to run new script after finishing previous scripts: script1, script2, script3. (2) put all code (from all 3 scripts) in one script and this way you don't have to read data from 2 sheets because you still will have data in memory.

yeah that sounds about right. I was trying to avoid putting all my scripts together, but I think reading the output file as a seperate script and doing the aggregations there is a good idea.

Yes this would be possible! The most intuitive way is to read the excel in a Python script with the help of Pandas:
df_sheet1 = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df_sheet2 = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='Sheet2')

Then, we can perform specific operations on the data such as concatting the data.
df_concat = pd.concat([df_sheet1, df_sheet2])

To perform the specific action you showed, we can run
df_grouped = df_concat.groupby(['Counterparty', 'Commodity'])['Total'].sum().reset_index()
df_pivot = df_grouped.pivot(index='Counterparty', columns='Commodity', values='Total').fillna(0)

To export this, we need to run:
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    df_pivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3')

Hope this helps!

I have updated the question with a more specific question. could you take a look? Your answer worked for this case, but I need to add to it a little bit
